# How to make a bulleted list with speech recognition?

Tags: speech-recognition, outline, speech-to-text

I'm trying to outline my textbook using a speech recognition tool (windows speech recognition, google's voice typing, or any other free software).
 
I haven't quite been able to get full outline capabilities using speech recognition. I would like to be able to:

- start a bulleted list (which works in google with "create bulleted list" and works in MS with "press ctrl+shift+L" but this also muted the mic)
  - make sub points (which works in google with "tab." MS is now muted so "press tab" won't work)
  - as many as I want
- Then create another main point (which is usually done with shift+tab but "shift+tab" doesn't work in google)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up typing control sequences and speaking text